# Complicated algorthm bidirectional tree - Clasifying parabioic 3D Motion

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree

Part of a program I'm working on requires sorting data points in 3D space and time to try and find items that match that of an object that is following a parabolic trajectory. These need to be linked.

I have started as follows:

Take each point (there could be more than one per time interval) and try and match it to previous points within a number of time intervals. This is done by each object holding a vector of shared pointers to the object they are linked too. This is backwards in time, i.e. Following the pointers will go back in time. Each object can be linked too via more than one object. This gives a bi-directional tree. The matching criteria at this stage is basic and just rules some of the noise.

I also have a physics class which gives out an error number, given 3 points in space and time. The error is a double that is a multiple of the distance away from the predicted location divided by the time difference.

What I need to do is work out the best way in C++ to find the items in this tree which are the best match for a parabola (i.e. Minimize the error) but also maximize the number of links and minimize the time difference between the links.

The issue is that following the tree, the number of options increases dramatically, it would be simple if only two points are required to determine the error number but three are.

Also Would recursion be good in this situation?

Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Why are people disrespecting this question without even leaving a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would forget about data structures and try and solve this as a problem in fitting a curve to data in the presence of large amounts of outlier noise. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANSAC

The basic idea is to try and find a subset of points that fit the data very well by repeating a two-step iteration.

Step one: adjust the parameters of the fit to increase how well they fit the current chosen subset of points.

Step two: given the current fitted parameters, choose the subset of points which fits them best.

From a random start, with a reasonable measure of fit, this process should increase the fit at every step until it converges. Try it from a number of different random starts and pick the best fit found at any time.